# How to handle duty cycle below deadtime in 2- and 3-level inverters

Tags: pwm, inverter, power-engineering, duty-cycle

When programming a pwm for a 2-lvl inverter what would be the suggested strategy for a duty cycle close to 0% or 100%, meaning when I cannot guarantee for dead time. What would cause less distortion limiting the duty cycle to 1/99% or setting bridges to always on/off?

Same question for a 3-lvl inverter.

From my guess in a 2-lvl I should set them to always on/off to archive over-modulation, in 3-lvl inverters (this might also be affected by the topology) I would clamp the duty cycle to 1/99% (anpc). Am I right with my guesses or is there a better way to handle this?

Info: I’m talking about grid connected inverters.

Comment: The strategy would be not to require duty cycles that are close to 0% or 100%.

Comment: About all you can do beyond avoiding it entirely, is dithering. If you needed 99%, alternate between 98% and 100% for example. Whether that total screws up your application I don't know.

Comment: If your high side drivers require charge pump operation (they use a bootstrap capacitor) you cannot go to 100% duty cycle (though arguably you can go to 0% as you don't need to drive the high side switch).

Comment: For a grid connected inverter, changing the output phase angle will reduce power while maintaining VA and alter the net power factor. If PF <>1 (likely) then you can improve it towards 1 overall with reduced or no net grid power delivered.